# C# Byte Handling

Tags: c#, vb6, byte, negation

I'm experiencing a bit of an issue while trying to convert some VB6 logic into C#.  In one of the VB6 functions, it has the following statement:

```
w = Not CByte(w)
```

Where w is a `long`.

In an example, after this line evaluates in VB6, I can see the following change: 

`Before:  w = 110`

`After:   w = 145`

However, in C#, I've rewritten the method to contain the following code:

```
w = ~(byte)w;
```

But, when I run the same example, I get these results, instead:

`Before:  w = 110`

`After:   w = -111`

I also get the same result doing:

```
w = ~(Convert.ToByte(w));
```

I was finally able to get the correct results with the following change:

```
w = ~(byte)w & 0xFF;
```

From what I can tell, it looks like C# is converting it to an `sbyte` even though it's not specified to do so.  My question is: is there some flaw in my logic?  Is this the only way to get the VB6 equivalent?

Comment: Your problem is your assumption as to *when* the arithmetic operation occurs is wrong. `~(byte)w` is not the same as `(byte)~w`.

Comment: See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx) for the `~` operator. In particular: *Bitwise complement operators are predefined for int, uint, long, and ulong.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`w` is a `long`, but let's say it's an `int`, it doesn't really matter except it's slightly easier to explain.

```
w = ~(byte)w;
```

Ok, so `w` is cast to a `byte` .. and then immediately back to `int` because that's what arithmetic operations do.

You could solve it by taking Justin's suggestion from the comments (which does the cast at the right moment: `(byte)~w`), or with this:

```
w ^= 0xFF;
```

That is not strictly the same thing though, it's different if `w` starts out with a value outside of the range of a `byte`.

Comment: Perfect!  That makes a lot of sense - great explanation. Thanks!